# dividing the screen to 4 Quarters doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I am dividing my screen to 4 Quarters but it doesn't work with all screen resolutions.I need it to always be 4quarters even by changing the window size.
here is the code:

```
body{
  height:800px; 
  }
 div{
  position:relative;
  border:1px solid red; 
  width:49.7%;
  height:49.7%;
  }
#Q1,#Q3{
 float:left;
  }
#Q2,#Q4{
 float:right;
 }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>

<div id="Q1"> </div>
<div id="Q2"> </div>
<div id="Q3"> </div>
<div id="Q4"> </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this CSS to make the height 100% and quarter it:

```
body{
  height:100%; 
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

div{
  position:relative;
  border:1px solid red; 
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;

  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#Q1,#Q3{
  float:left;
}
#Q2,#Q4{
  float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The computed width of the boxes exceeds the total available space in lower screens. This is because the border of `1px` around the elements.

You could give the `div` elements a [`box-sizing: border-box;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) declaration so that their `width` would be calculated including padding and borders.

**[Example Here](http://jsbin.com/samigi/2/edit)**

```css
div {
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

---

In addition, if you want to resize the `height` of the boxes with the respect to the height of the body, note to set `height: 100%` on `body` and `html`  as well.

You have to specify the height of `html` to get `height: 100%` to work for the `<body>`. This because a percentage value of `height` property is relative to the height of box's containing block.

**[Updated Example Here](http://jsbin.com/samigi/3/edit)**

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%; 
  padding : 0;
  margin  : 0; /* Remove the default 8px margin around the body */
}
```

Also note that UAs apply a default `margin` to the `<body>` by default. Make sure you have reset the user agent stylesheet.

Comment: no i need it always dividing the screen to 4 quarters even by changing the window size

Comment: @MelodyHajian Have you looked at the provided [example](http://jsbin.com/samigi/2/edit)?

Comment: That is exactly what the example does.

Comment: One problem with this answer. It doesn't explain that `body{height:800px;}` that's in the original code may be an issue given that OP wants "it to always be 4quarters even by changing the window size"

Comment: Could you please stick to english, so that other people might learn from this question as well? ;o)

Comment: @MelodyHajian Also mind [resetting the user agent stylesheet](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).